# How can I create this UI navigation control?

Tags: android

This is a picture of my phone (Android 2.1 with HKC Sense):

[image]

The bit that's got a red border around it is in the Clock app and the Media player on my phone. What is it called? Is it a standard Android interface control?

I've been trying to figure out how to get something like this for the past while and I'm not seeing anything immediately obvious.

I've seen a lot of people referring to the ActionBar or Split ActionBar, but that seems to be something that is anchored to the top. I need this to be at the bottom without any component on the top.

*please excuse

1. It's an actual pic of the phone, rather than a screenshot - the screenshot app I downloaded wouldn't work.
2. The fact that the pic was taken with an iPhone, and that the apple logo is clearly reflected in the pic.

Comment: What you need is a Tab bar, and android guidlines recommend putting it on the top of the screen. http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Split ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

And that will force the action bar items to be hosted on the bottom of the screen for narrow devices, mostly phones. When this flag is set, no components are hosted on the top of the ActionBar, unless you use tab navigation.

[See example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3y6w.png)

Keep in mind though, that should you be displaying the layout on a non-narrow device, like a tablet, then the items will be attached to the top ActionBar.

**Some other things to consider**

- Creating a custom view, which you can set to the bottom of the layout. The View would be a scrollable ListView per say, and you can add as many icons as you'd like to it. Here's an [example](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). That would not be a standard nav pattern though.

Comment: That's the point of the question I'm asking - I want to avoid any items from being attached to the top. I want a control that is anchored to the bottom at all times.

Comment: What is the app in the screenshot?

Comment: Looks really nice! Is it in the Google Play?